# Adding string before request body in Retforit

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-android

I want to add string before request body in Retrofit request.
What i mean:

```
data={"action":"users.login","data":{"email":"test@gmail.com", "password":"password"}}
```

But Retofit allows only request such type:

```
{"action":"users.login","data":{"email":"test@gmail.com", "password":"password"}}
```

Here's my code of method in interface:

```
@POST("/api")
Observable<RequestResult> loginAction(@Body Request<User> userRequest);
```

Here's code from login activity:

```
User user = new User();
user.setEmail("email");
user.setPassword("password");

    subscription.add(
            service.loginAction(
                    new Request<>("users.login", user))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<RequestResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onNext(RequestResult requestResult) {
                }
            })
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,if you want to add string before EVERY request, they can be specified using an [OkHttp interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors).

Just like this,

```
    client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();

            String time = DateUtil.getDefaultDateTime(new Date());


            RequestBody body = request.body();

            String bodyData = "data=";

            if (body != null) {
                Buffer bufferedSink = new Buffer();
                request.body().writeTo(bufferedSink);
                bodyData += bufferedSink.readUtf8();
            }

            String tokenData = AppContext.get(ContextConstant.TOKEN, "");

            String keyData = request.url() + bodyData + time + tokenData;

            String key = Encryption.genKey(keyData);

            String userId = AppContext.get(ContextConstant.CURRENT_USER_ID, "");

            String authorization = Encryption.getHeaderValue(userId, AppContext.getInstance().getUUID());

            Request.Builder requestBuilder = request.newBuilder();

            requestBuilder.header("X-key", key);
            requestBuilder.header("Authorization", authorization.replace("\n", ""));
            requestBuilder.header("X-API-Version", AppConstant.API_VERSION);
            requestBuilder.header("X-Data-version", AppConstant.DATA_VERSION);
            requestBuilder.header("X-Request-Time", time);

            Request okRequest = requestBuilder.build();

            Response response = chain.proceed(okRequest);

            return response;
        }

    });
```

However, I only use this way for specified Header, not for specified RequestBody.

Secondly, if you use Gson,(unfortunately, you didn't)

```
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat(DateUtil.FORMAT)
            .registerTypeAdapter(User.class, new UserDeserializer())
            .registerTypeAdapter(User.class, new UserSerializer())
            .create();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(AppConstant.HOST)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .client(client)
            .build();
```

In the UserSerializer,

```
public class UserSerializer implements JsonSerializer<User> {
@Override
public JsonElement serialize(User src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
    return new JsonPrimitive("data=" + src.toString());
}
```

}

I think it could be round by {}....

```
{data={"action":"users.login","data":{"email":"test@gmail.com", "password":"password"}}}
```

Finally, I suggest you use a wrapper class UserData encapsulating "data=" in request string.

I use Retrofit 2.0 beta 2.

Good Luck!